Next.14 Build Error - OmitWithTag<typeof "">
I'm using Next.14 to develop an app and in the Build process it always ends the process like this here:

C:\Users\HP\Documents\UP\next-auth>npm run build

> nextauth@0.1.0 build
> next build

  ▲ Next.js 14.2.3
  - Environments: .env

   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ✓ Compiled successfully
   Linting and checking validity of types  ...Failed to compile.

.next/types/app/api/auth/actions/route.ts:8:13
Type error: Type 'OmitWithTag<typeof import("C:/Users/HP/Documents/UP/next-auth/app/api/auth/actions/route"), "POST" | "config" | "generateStaticParams" | "revalidate" | "dynamic" | "dynamicParams" | "fetchCache" | ... 8 more ... | "PATCH", "">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'.
  Property 'Login' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '(email: string, password: string) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'never'.

   6 |
   7 | // Check that the entry is a valid entry
>  8 | checkFields<Diff<{
     |             ^
   9 |   GET?: Function
  10 |   HEAD?: Function
  11 |   OPTIONS?: Function



I separated all the server-components into different files and consulted the build file but I didn't find anything that could be useful other than this message
 Type 'OmitWithTag<typeof import("C:/Users/HP/Documents/UP/next-auth/app/api/auth/actions/route"), "POST" | "config" | "generateStaticParams" | "revalidate" | "dynamic" | "dynamicParams" | "fetchCache" | ... 8 more ... | "PATCH", "">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'.
  Property 'Login' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '(email: string, password: string) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'never'.

It says that the parameters being passed do not correspond to the Never type.
Can you tell me how to solve this problem?
